# Why I am unable to scan iBeacon with UUID provided inside services using flutter_reactive_ble in my flutter project?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble inside my flutter project. But I am unable to scan ibeacon if I provide UUID inside services, I think I am missing something.

On the other hand, it's working fine if the empty array is provided inside with services.

here's my piece of code :

```
 _subscription = await FlutterReactiveBle().scanForDevices(
        withServices: [Uuid.parse('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111')],
        // withServices: [],//working fine with empty array
        scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
        requireLocationServicesEnabled:
            true).listen(onDeviceFound, onError: onError);
```

Here's the simulator screenshot:

[image]

any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is that the Flutter package you are using is not scanning for beacon advertisements** (iBeacon, AltBeacon) but for BLE Service UUID advertisements.  Note the `withServices` in this line of code:

```
FlutterReactiveBle().scanForDevices(
        withServices: [Uuid.parse('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111')],
```

This means you are telling the library to scan for advertised BLE Services with the given Service UUIDs.  These are completely different kinds of BLE advertisements than BLE Beacon advertisements.  Unfortunately, **the package you are using won't do what you want.**

You might try [Flutter Beacon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_beacon).

Comment: Strange cuz I am able to see broadcasted beacons in the scanning results done by FlutterReactiveBle if no service UUID is provided. It's just that when I am broadcasting an ibeacon, I am unable to scan it on the ios devices (it's visible on android though).  So the  only case when I am unable to scan is : IOS to IOS. Then I came to know that in case of IOS devices u need to define proximityUUID to scan for ibeacons. that's why I am providing UUID. is there any other way I can detect ibeacons ?

Comment: When you get detections on Android, the UUIDs you see are not BLE Beacon UUIDs.  You are seeing GATT Service UUIDs, because the package you are using looks for GATT Service UUIDs not BLE Beacon UUIDs.  It's not looking for the right thing.  You need to use a different scanning package like mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and yes using the plugin u stated above I can scan ibeacons, but now the problem is that I can only scan ibeacons using this plugin (unable to scan AltBeacon). Might end up using both at the same time to cover all the cases.

Comment: Also can we broadcast as Altbeacon instead of ibeacon on IOS devices ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, iOS does not let you advertise AltBeacon. It only support two types of advertising:  iBeacon (a specific BLE Manufacturer Advertisement format) and BLE GATT Service Advertisements.